# Is there a way to add an ID to a file on includeJS array in Typo3 8?

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-8.x

Or in `includeJSFooter` I have tried

```
includeJSFooter {
        initJavascript = path/to/file/init.js
        initJavascript.id = initJavascript
    }
```

but It does not work and I do not see any option [in the docs](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/Setup/Page/Index.html#includejs-array) but maybe I have missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible. For this kind of inclusion you need to use `page.headerData` or `page.footerData`.
See: https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/Setup/Page/Index.html#headerdata

Comment: Sadly in that way the included file does not have a query string for cache

Comment: Why do you need an ID at this position?

Comment: I wanted to get the cache string in the client side. Without query all the script tags.

Comment: Did you have a look in Install Tool -> All configuration -> option "[FE][versionNumberInFilename]"? Maybe this can help as well.

Comment: There I can just configure how the string es added. Would be nice to get the timestamp of the last time the cache was cleared. I will ask if that is possible.